# Magento 2.2.5 Unable to get orderGrandTotal() in success.phtml

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.2, grand-total, order-success-page

I'm trying to get access to the grand total of the order but for some reason am unable to access this variable.

I have tried multiple solutions by creation modules but nothing seems to be working.

***success.phtml***

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success */ ?>

<!---- Onefeed Tracking Code ---->
<?php
//-------------------------------------------
// GET MAGENTO 2 ORDER VALUES FOR TRACKING CODE
//-------------------------------------------
$orderId = $block->getOrderId();
echo $block->getOrder();
$total = 2;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var of_ssid = '362-1';
  var cs = '<?php echo $total; ?>';
  var oi = '<?php echo $orderId; ?>';
  var it = 1;
  var id = '';
  var pairs = document.cookie.split("; "),
    count = pairs.length, parts;
  while (count--) {
    parts = pairs[count].split("=");
    if (parts[0] === "user" && parts[1] === "usr")
      id = parts[2];
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/t.js"></script>
<noscript>
    <img border="0" src="https://tracking.onefeed.co.uk/ProcessProductCheckout.ashx?of_ssid=362-1&cs=<?php echo $total; ?>&it=1&oi=<?php echo $orderId; ?>" />
</noscript>

<!---- End Onefeed Tracking Code ---->
```

success.php

```
<?php

namespace Creation\OrderSuccess\Block;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success {

    public function getOrder() {
        return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
    }

}
```

***echo $block->getOrder() outputs null, if I echo $block->getGrandTotal() I also get null.***

I can't seem to figure out where I'm missing the connection to access this data.

Comment: Can i assume that when your testing you are refreshing the page? if so when the page is refreshed that data is removed to prevent this on a temporary basis i never recommend editing the core files on a permenant basis only for quick testing. go to vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php on line 22 comment out $session->clearQuote();which will prevent the checkout from clearing itself so you can do proper test

Comment: Yeah you are correct although I have already tried this and still wasn't getting the data I needed. Are you able to access the quote inside of success.php?

Comment: I am able to retreive the last order id and then load that via my own block i never extend the success block as i prefer my code to be independand of core blocks as magento is constantly changing class names and depricating things

Comment: Do you have an example I would be able to take reference from?

Comment: please see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work no issue tried and tested.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

class Success extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $scopeConfig;

    protected $checkoutSession;

    protected $orderModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,  
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,       
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
        array $data = []        
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);       
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_orderModel = $orderModel;
    }

    public function getRealOrderId()
    {
        $lastorderId = $this->_checkoutSession->getLastOrderId();
        return $lastorderId;
    }   

    public function getOrder() {

        $orderId = $this->getRealOrderId();
        $_order = $this->_orderModel->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

        return $_order;
    }

}
```